# Laravel - End of lifecycle

Tags: php, laravel

I'm aware of the Laravel terminable middleware, however I'm trying to work with events here and as such it does not work. When I plug my terminable middleware into the route, it is called, but the events do not fire. When I remove it, the events fire, but obviously middleware is not invoked.

Is there some kind of `terminate` mechanism that's used before the end of the application' lifecycle that I can plug into?

Comment: write some code please.

Comment: @GiacomoM, this is a question about Laravel concepts and architecture, I suppose you may ignore the first few sentences about what works and what does not.

Comment: I've added this to the end of index.php, after everything has finished working, including events.